# Generating a C++ classes from IDL file using MICO (CORBA)

Tags: c++, corba, idl

I wan to generate a `C++` classes from a `IDL` file using `MICO` in the contxet of `CORBA`. I download the `mico-2.3.13.zip` but iI don't know how to use it. Please if someone can help me and thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

The answer would probably be longer that would comfortably fit in a short reply, but here are some pages with helpful starter info.

This class webpage has a mini tutorial using mico

http://www.cs.wichita.edu/~chang/lecture/cs843/program/mico-idl.html

Here's another fairly simple tutorial page

http://people.inf.ethz.ch/roemer/micodoc/node16.html

Answer (score 1):

You first need to compile MICO from the sources. Depending on your operating system and environment this will require different steps. In linux/mac os x they are basically calling the `./configure` script and then `make` if it did not fail. Under windows I think that you can call `nmake` directly (with some options, read the README files).

After compilation completes (this may take a few minutes) and if everything goes fine, you should have the executables and can use them to create your own CORBA interfaces and services.